# Is it always true that if $I+A$ is Non singular then $I-A$ is also Non singular

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

Is it always true that if $I+A$ is Non singular then $I-A$ is also Non singular?

Since $I+A$ is Non singular we have

$$(I+A)^{-1}=I-A+A^2-A^3+A^4-A^5+\cdots$$ that is

$$(I+A)^{-1}=(I-A)+A^2(I-A)+A^4(I-A)+\cdots$$ $\implies$

$$(I+A)^{-1}=(I-A)(I+A^2+A^4+\cdots)$$
   taking Determinant on both sides we get

$$\frac{1}{Det(I+A)}=Det(I-A)Det(I+A^2+A^4+\cdots)$$

since LHS is non zero, RHS should be non zero which means $Det(I-A)$ cannot be zero. hence $I-A$ is also Non singular. Is this proof valid?

Comment: No. What if $A=I$?

Comment: The series expansion may not always converge.

Comment: ok so if impose condition that $A \ne \pm I$ i guess proof is correct

Comment: Still no, what if $$A = \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} $$?

Comment: It's important to try a few simple examples before diving into something complicated.

Comment: ok fine so my proof is valid only when the series converges. but can i know for which matrices the series will converge

Comment: It converges when A is a convergent matrix ie when A raised to a power eventually equals zero (at infinity). You need all of the eigenvalues(spectral radius) |λ|<1, then it will converge. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergent_matrix

Comment: $I+A$ is nonsingular iff $-1$  is not one of $A$'s eigenvalues. $I-A$ is nonsingular iff $+1$ is not one of $A$'s eigenvalues. Do these things have anything to do with one another? Note that as someone else just commented, your sequence converges only when all of $A$'s eigenvalues have $|\lambda|<1$ so your proof has no bearing on your question. (It only applies to $A$ for which $I-A$ is nonsingular).

Answer (score 3):

If you use divergent series, you can prove astonishing results. For instance, if
$$
S=1+2+4+\dots+2^n+\dotsb
$$
then
$$
2S=2+4+8+\dots+2^{n+1}+\dotsb=S-1
$$
whence $S=-1$. This is obviously nonsense (in the real numbers) and the problem is exactly in the series not being convergent.

Your matrix series $I-A+A^2-A^3+\dotsb$ isn't convergent either, unless all eigenvalues of $A$ have modulus less than $1$. Of course, in this case $1$ cannot be an eigenvalue of $A$, so $I-A$ is nonsingular.

Note that $I+I$ is nonsingular, but obviously $I-I$ is singular.

Answer (score 2):

No, that fails if for example $A=I$. What happens is that the series does not converge.

However if the series $\sum A^j$ convergse absolutely we know that $(I-A)\sum{A^j} = I = (I+A)\sum{(-A)^j} = I$. This happens if the norm of $A$ is less than $1$. If the norm is larger than $1$ the series will definitely diverge (but that does not necessarily mean that $I+A$ is singular, just that if it's non-singular that the inverse can't be found using the series).

So what you can say is that if $|A|<1$ then both $I+A$ and $I-A$ are non-singular.

For $|A|=1$ then $I+A$ and $I-A$ may or may not be non-singular. It is for example non-singular if $A=\begin{pmatrix}0&1\\0&0\end{pmatrix}$ then both $I+A$ and $I-A$ are non-singular. Tho case where $A-I$ is singuar is of course $A=I$.

Note: the norm of a matrix is the same as the modulus of the largest eigenvalue (if it has eigenvalues).

Comment: "if it has eigenvalues" - I wonder, can a matrix not to have eigenvalues?

Comment: @Widawensen Depends on whether you count complex eigenvalues. Anyway the formulation should suit any reader whether they are familiar with complex or not (those who ar familiar with complex should realize that one can condition a true statement with anything even if that is universally true).

Comment: I see,  you mean real eigenvalues.

Comment: @Widawensen I also mean it doesn't matter (but yes I didn't assume that the OP was familiar with complex). If you meant complex the formulation would be valid nevertheless.

Comment: It's appeared in another answer, but a key point about "what you can say is that if $I+ A $ is non singular and $|A|<1$ then $I-A$ is non singular as well" is that while that statement is true I suppose, $I-A$ being nonsingular follows from $|A| <1$ alone. $I+A$'s nonsingularness has nothing to do with it (although it would *follow* from  $|A|<1$ that $I+A$ is nonsingular)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I didn't think about that, but of course you're correct about that - I've updated my answer to reflect that.